# why web2py DAL query on double field gives random result

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

in models.py

```
    db.define_table('item',
        Field('point','double')
    )
```

query is :

```
db.item.point >= float(min_amount)
```

this results in wrong sets

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way to execute `select` query.

See Following query, it will return all the records from `item` table whose `point` value is greater or equal to `min_amount`

```
result_set = db(db.item.point >= float(min_amount)).select()
```

Read- [select query in web2py](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#select)

Comment: i have written the select query like yours only , what i have shown is the query that i m making.

Comment: @ShashankSingh can you show some more code? and what exactly you wanted to do? where you have written this query? in which file? Edit the question and add more details.